# How to gather byte occurrence statistics in binary file?

Tags: command-line, files, binary, statistics

I'd like to know the equivalent of

```
cat inputfile | sed 's/\(.\)/\1\n/g' | sort | uniq -c
```

presented in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4174113/how-to-gather-characters-usage-statistics-in-text-file-using-unix-commands for production of character usage statistics in text files for binary files counting simple bytes instead of characters, i.e. output should be in the form of

```
18383 57
12543 44
11555 127
 8393 0
```

It doesn't matter if the command takes as long as the referenced one for characters.

If I apply the command for characters to binary files the output contains statistics for arbitrary long sequences of unprintable characters (I don't seek explanation for that).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With GNU `od`:

```
od -vtu1 -An -w1 my.file | sort -n | uniq -c
```

Or more efficiently with `perl` (also outputs a count (0) for bytes that don't occur):

```
perl -ne 'BEGIN{$/ = \4096};
          $c[$_]++ for unpack("C*");
          END{for ($i=0;$i<256;$i++) {
              printf "%3d: %d\n", $i, $c[$i]}}' my.file
```

Comment: In order to get the numbers in the first row recognized correctly I had to add `| sort -n` and `| sort -n -r` for descending order respectively (sorting was not part of the question). Sorting might be done better...

Comment: Seems a little overkill to have to sort the entire file, but worked OK for me.

Comment: Good point @Karl, though not requested, using `sort -n` here makes a lot more sense. Answer updated.

Answer (score 5):

For large files using sort will be slow. I wrote a short C program to solve the equivalent problem ([see this gist for Makefile with tests](https://gist.github.com/bjodah/9c95c6814947e854dab5)):

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define BUFFERLEN 4096

int main(){
    // This program reads standard input and calculate frequencies of different
    // bytes and present the frequences for each byte value upon exit.
    //
    // Example:
    //
    //     $ echo "Hello world" | ./a.out
    //
    // Copyright (c) 2015 Björn Dahlgren
    // Open source: MIT License

    long long tot = 0; // long long guaranteed to be 64 bits i.e. 16 exabyte
    long long n[256]; // One byte == 8 bits => 256 unique bytes

    const int bufferlen = BUFFERLEN;
    char buffer[BUFFERLEN];
    int i;
    size_t nread;

    for (i=0; i<256; ++i)
        n[i] = 0;

    do {
        nread = fread(buffer, 1, bufferlen, stdin);
        for (i = 0; i < nread; ++i)
            ++n[(unsigned char)buffer[i]];
        tot += nread;
    } while (nread == bufferlen);
    // here you may want to inspect ferror of feof

    for (i=0; i<256; ++i){
        printf("%d ", i);
        printf("%f\n", n[i]/(float)tot);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

usage:

```sh
gcc main.c
cat my.file | ./a.out
```

Comment: Do you have a test? There're no comments in the code. It's in general not a good idea to use untested and publish untested or uncommented code - not matter whether it's common practice. The possibility to review revisions is also limited on this platform, consider an explicit code hosting platform.

Comment: @KarlRichter tests were a good idea to add. I found the old version choked on '\0' characters. This version should work (passes a few basic tests at least).

Comment: `fgets` gets a line, not a buffer-full. You're scanning the 4096-byte full buffer for each line read from stdin. You need `fread` here, not `fgets`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas great - didn't know of fread (seldom do I/O from C). updated example to use fread instead.

Comment: I've added an `if` block around the printf statements, that makes the output more readable if some bytes don't occur in the input file: https://gist.github.com/martinvonwittich/2f0a9e5dcf63cb316765260694b73172

Answer (score 3):

As mean, sigma and CV are often important when judging statistic data of the content of binary files, I've created a cmdline program that graphs all this data as an ascii circle of byte deviations from sigma.
 http://wp.me/p2FmmK-96
It can be used with grep, xargs and other tools to extract statistics.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

The `recode` program can do this quickly even for large files, either frequency statistics either for bytes or for the characters of various character sets.  E.g. to count byte frequencies:

```
$ echo hello there > /tmp/q
$ recode latin1/..count-characters < /tmp/q
1  000A LF   1  0020 SP   3  0065 e    2  0068 h    2  006C l    1  006F o
1  0072 r    1  0074 t
```

**Caution** - *specify your file to recode as standard input, otherwise it will silently replace it with the character frequencies!*

Use `recode utf-8/..count-characters < file` to treat the input file as utf-8.  Many many other character sets are available, and it will fail if the file contains any illegal characters.

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to Stephane's `od` answer but it shows the ASCII value of the byte. It is also sorted by frequency / number of occurences.

```
xxd -c1 my.file|cut -c10-|sort|uniq -c|sort -nr
```

I don't think this is efficient since many processes are started but it's good for single files, particularly small files.